# Getting html content between specific <div> tag only

Tags: perl, html-parsing

I wrote the following code to scrape text content between `<div id=aaa-bbb>` and the next `</div>` tag, but it only prints out the whole HTML source.

```
use LWP::Simple;

$url = 'http://domain.com/?xxxxxxx';

my $content = get($url);

$data =~ m/<div id="aaa-bbb">(.*?)<\/div>/g;

if (is_success(getprint($url))) {
    print $_;
 }

# or using the following line directly without if statement
print $data;
```

The HTML piece that I'm interested in looks like this:

```
<div id="aaa-bbb">
<p>text text text text text text text text text</p><p>text text text</p>
</div>
```

That specific `div` tag id appears only once in the whole HTML document.

I'm also looking to strip out `<p></p>` tags or tidy the output by line breaks for storing as a text file later or reusing.

After reading your valuable comments I tried using
[`WWW::Mechanize`](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW%3a%3aMechanize)
and
[`WWW::Mechanize::TreeBuilder`](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aTreeBuilder)
instead, like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use WWW::Mechanize; 
use WWW::Mechanize::TreeBuilder; 

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new; 
WWW::Mechanize::TreeBuilder->meta->apply($mech); 

$mech->get( 'domain.com/?xxxxxx' ); 

my @list = $mech->find('div id="aaa-bbb"'); # or <div id="aaa-bbb"> or "<div id="aaa-bbb">"
foreach (@list) { 
  print $_->as_text(); 
}
```

It works for simple tags but can't get it to work with `<div id="aaaa">`. It just exits the script without printing anything. I used double and single quotes, it already has double quotes inside the tag id.

Comment: Don't use regular expressions for this. Get an HTML parser (such as HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath).

Comment: It's 2013. Use an XML parser.

Comment: What do you think `$data =~ m/<div id="aaa-bbb">(.*?)<\/div>/g;` is doing?

Comment: It's HTML, don't use an XML parser (unless it has an HTML parsing mode).

Comment: http://htmlparsing.com/perl.html has examples of how to parse HTML properly with Perl.  http://htmlparsing.com/regexes.html explains why regexes are a bad idea.

Comment: thanks guys for all your comments, i used this instead: use WWW::Mechanize;
use WWW::Mechanize::TreeBuilder;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;
WWW::Mechanize::TreeBuilder->meta->apply($mech);

$mech->get( 'http://domain.com/?xxxxxx' );


my @list = $mech->find('<div id="aaa-bbb">');


foreach (@list) {
    print $_->as_text();
} it works for simple tags but can't get it to work with <div id="aaaa"> it just exit the script without printing anything, i used double and single quotes, it already has double quotes inside tag id

Comment: ok, thanks for the note, i tried before to accept previous answers but the site system didn't let me, will try again now.

Comment: @SilverShadow: We can't read your code when you paste it as a comment.  Please go back and edit your original post to include it there.

Comment: The `find` method allows you to look for elements only by their tag name. To check an attribute as well you need `$mech->look_down(_tag => 'div', id => 'aaa-bbb')`

Answer (score 5):

This type of parsing is much easier with a DOM parser. My parser of choice is [Mojo::DOM](http://p3rl.org/Mojo::DOM) which is part of the [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us) suite.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Mojo::UserAgent;
my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;

my $dom = $ua->get( 'domain.com/?xxxxxx' )->res->dom; 

my $text = $dom->at('#aaa-bbb')->all_text;
```

The `at` method is a special case of the `find` method, which finds all the instances; `at` finds the first (or in your case, only). The `#` is the [CSS](http://p3rl.org/Mojo::DOM::CSS) selector syntax for ids.